# jQuery group of checkbox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have two group of checkbox `newBuilding` & `oldBuilding`.

1. Idea over here is I can select checkbox only one of the group.
2. In each group there is checkbox name other area, so I when click on it, it will show and hide textbox next to it.

Now to achieve first point, lets for example that already we have `oldBuilding` checkboxes are checked and I if I click one of the `newBuilding` checkbox then it will remove the check from `oldBuilding` group but **`newBuilding` checkbox will not get checked but just get focus,** I have to click again to check.

What I found out that above issue happen when I call trigger event. How can I overcome the issue

Code for other area

```
$("#chkOldBuildingOtherAreas").change(function () {
  if ($("#chkOldBuildingOtherAreas").is(":checked"))
     $("#txOldOtherAreas").show();
  else
    $("#txOldOtherAreas").hide();
  });

$("#chkNewBuildingOtherAreas").change(function () {
  if ($("#chkNewBuildingOtherAreas").is(":checked"))
    $("#txNewOtherAreas").show();
  else
    $("#txNewOtherAreas").hide();
});
```

Code for removing check mark from other groups

```
$("input[name='oldBuilding']").change(function () {
  if ($("input[name='newBuilding']:checked").length > 0) {
    $("input[name='newBuilding']").removeAttr('checked');
    $("#chkNewBuildingOtherAreas").trigger("change");
  }
});

$("input[name='newBuilding']").change(function () {
  if ($("input[name='oldBuilding']:checked").length > 0) {
    $("input[name='oldBuilding']").removeAttr('checked');
    $("#chkOldBuildingOtherAreas").trigger("change");
  }
});
```

My jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/milindsaraswala/wchrwjnx/

Comment: don't you cry blood looking at that code formatting of yours?

Comment: done formatting to the code ;)

Comment: thanks, that's a lot easier to read now, but can you also provide example of that html for checkboxes groups you have (better at jsfiddle) so everyone can try it out and tinker with solution?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1ny36nwL/2/ - you don't need to trigger change since you haven't stopped original event and it still was triggering. so click happened twice and that's why it was un-checked. if i understood what you want correctly...

Comment: thank for reply but issue is that if u have clicked other area before than I need to hide text box also which in your case it is not getting hide

Comment: sorry, i was wrong. if you add `debugger` to the start of each `$("input[name='oldBuilding']")`/`$("input[name='newBuilding']")` listeners you can see that they are triggered 3 times (initial + each `.trigger("change");`)

Comment: the only solution I can think of is to hide them manually instead of triggering change, but I guess you already tried that https://jsfiddle.net/1ny36nwL/3/

Comment: works as charm. I m dumb. why I did not think of that. Kindly add as answer so I mark as answer :)

Comment: you can try something more complex - like create new function `resetState` that will uncheck checkboxes, clear and hide text input for given group and call it when checkbox in other group clicked

Comment: ok, I will add example of that more complex solution and post it as an answer

Comment: Thank you. I will wait for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/1ny36nwL/4/

```
var groups = ['.oldGroup', '.newGroup'];
$(groups.join(',')).find('input[type=text]').hide();

function resetGroup(selector) {
    //clear and hide texts
    $('input[type=text]', selector).val('').hide();
    //uncheck boxes
    $('input[type=checkbox]', selector).removeAttr('checked');
}

$("input[name='oldBuilding']").change(function(e) {
    if (this.id == 'chkOldBuildingOtherAreas') {
        $("#txOldOtherAreas").toggle();
    }
    resetGroup('.newGroup');
});

$("input[name='newBuilding']").change(function(e) {
    if (this.id == 'chkNewBuildingOtherAreas') {
        $("#txNewOtherAreas").toggle();
    }
    resetGroup('.oldGroup');
});
```

as you can see I added `groups` var which can contain multiple groups (not only two), but code need to be changed a little more for that to work

you need to detect id/class of current group by something like `$(this).closest('.form-group').id` and reset every group except current group. in that way you can leave only one change function which will be universal

oh and you also need to add some class for checkbox that contain text input, and if that checkbox is clicked, trigger toggle for input. so it won't be `if (this.id == 'chkNewBuildingOtherAreas') {` but something like `if ($(this).hasClass('has-input'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code to fix the problem (Tested in fiddle):

```
$('#txNewOtherAreas, #txOldOtherAreas').hide();

$('input[name="oldBuilding"]').on('click', function(){
    if($('input[name="newBuilding"]').is(':checked')){
      $('input[name="newBuilding"]').removeAttr('checked');
      $('#txNewOtherAreas').hide();
    }
});

$('input[name="newBuilding"]').on('click', function(){
    if($('input[name="oldBuilding"]').is(':checked')){
      $('input[name="oldBuilding"]').removeAttr('checked');
      $('#txOldOtherAreas').hide();
    }
});

$('#chkNewBuildingOtherAreas').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $('#txNewOtherAreas').show();
    } else {
       $('#txNewOtherAreas').hide();
    }
});

$('#chkOldBuildingOtherAreas').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
       $('#txOldOtherAreas').show();
    } else {
       $('#txOldOtherAreas').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: There is the code if you see in jsfiddler from line 3 to 9

Comment: Checked your code in fiddle and updated my comment above with solution as suggestion. The problem with your code is `change` event. When you are calling `change` function on one type of checkboxes, then you are also using `removeAttr()` for removing check from other type of checkboxes. which is ultimately triggering the `change` event on respective checkbox, and making your clicked checkbox **unchecked** again.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this in your code. It should work.

```
                    $("#txOldOtherAreas").hide();
                    $("#txNewOtherAreas").hide();
                    $("input[name='oldBuilding']").change(function (e) {
                        $("input[name='newBuilding']").removeAttr('checked');
                        e.target.checked = true;
                        if (e.target.id == "chkOldBuildingOtherAreas") {
                            $("#txOldOtherAreas").show();
                            $("#txNewOtherAreas").hide();
                        } else {
                            $("#txNewOtherAreas").hide();
                        }
                    });
                    $("input[name='newBuilding']").change(function (e) {
                        $("input[name='oldBuilding']").removeAttr('checked');
                        e.target.checked = true;
                        if (e.target.id == "chkNewBuildingOtherAreas") {
                            $("#txNewOtherAreas").show();
                            $("#txOldOtherAreas").hide();
                        } else {
                            $("#txOldOtherAreas").hide();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: No, if I had clicked other area where it will show text box which is not getting hide